# How to open the output file in C without keyboard/trackpad?

Tags: c, file, pointers, io

I have a program in C that takes a bmp file as input. It reads the pixels and then writes them into another bmp file after some modification of pixel triplet.

The new bmp file thus created in my directory, I need to manually open it up.

Is it possible to open the output file directly in my console by executing a command in the program itself?

**Rough outline of program**

`<read from existing bmp file>
<modify the pixels>
<write to new bmp file>
**<open bmp file by using trackpad/keyboard>**`

I would like to automate the **last step**, if possible.

Comment: What is your environement? (Mac, Linux, Windows, ...)?

Comment: Neither trackpad nor keyboard are mentioned in C standards. So your question does not make sense (or you need to explain a lot more about your computer, hardware, operating system)

Comment: Why _open bmp file by using trackpad/keyboard_ and not just _open bmp file_?

Comment: I think you simply mean that you want to execute/run/open the newly saved bmp file in photo viewer program or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **system** function to open image editor program. Please note that, **system** call is platform dependent and is not guaranteed to work uniformly in all platforms.

For example, if you are using windows, you can open image file using *mspaint*

```
system("mspaint [path to image file]");
```